# rails html to pdf

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, pdf

I have the following action in a controller

```
def save
  client = Pdfcrowd::Client.new("asdads", "asdads")

  pdf = client.convertHtml(params[:gender])

  send_data(pdf, 
            :filename => "untitled.pdf",
            :type => "application/pdf",
            :disposition => "attachment")
rescue Pdfcrowd::Error => why
  render :text => why
end
```

I want to get Html code from the view and then convert it to pdf

I am using the pdfcrowd gem

I also have this line in my view:

```
<% params[:gender => compareGender(@task) ] %>
```

compareGender is a method that returns svg code

This is not working can someone suggest an alternative solution?

Comment: Define "not working". Is it displaying an error? If so, what? Is it working, but giving you unexpected results? Explain them and post an example if possible.

Comment: it gives out this error 400 - No data to convert. Missing src field.

Comment: I just want to know how to pass a string from the view to an action in the controller

Comment: @user2216744 your question is not well-specified.  Honestly, it's totally unclear.  Your comment about string-passing makes it no-closer to clear.  Help us help you

Comment: shouldn't you contact support on pdfcrowd, since it's a paid service?

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices. You can use Rails' render_to_string method to get the rendered view into a string variable that you can then convert to PDF, OR you can skip rails' rendering and use the Erb library directly to render your view into a string. I think the latter will probably work better for you, and also protect you from any changes rails might make to the render_to_string API.

If your views are in Haml instead of Erb, just use haml to render them instead.